# Need a definition for the term "FPGA image"

Tags: fpga

I can't seem to find a definition for the term "FPGA image". I think it is just another term for an FPGA configuration that would be stored in say a SPI flash memory chip but I'm not sure.

Comment: That is correct. An "image" is a general term for a raw binary file for any programmable device.

Answer (score 4):

FPGA image, FPGA configuration, and FPGA bitstream, and possibly a few more terms are all essentially synonyms. It's what gets loaded onto the FPGA through the configuration interface. Doesn't have to be stored in an SPI flash specifically.